# Storybook - React Implementar componente creado en StoryBook en proyecto React

Tags: reactjs

supongo que la consulta puede ser muy obia para algunos, es la primara vez que mi piden crear componentes con StoryBook, lo estamos haciendo de manera independiente de el proeycto react, no lo estamos instalando junto con el proyecto React, la consulta es una vez que tenga creado mis componentes en StoryBook, cual es la forma o como se peude utilizar los componentes creados en StoryBook en mi proyecto React, como los Utilizo, he encontrado Documentación como implementar y crear componentes en Storybook, pero no encuentro información como integrarlo con un proyecto React como lo incorporo o utilizo en mi proyecto, se que también se peude usar con Angular,  Vue, pero no hay mucha información de como integrarlo al proyecto o como usarlo esto es mas una consulta si tienen alguna guía ejemplo donde puedo encontrar información de como integrar a un proyecto, he buscado pero no encuentro una explicación de como utilizar en un proyecto.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Haciendo a mano tomando los estilos segun lo que veo. Ya que no es codigo reactjs esta personalizado

Comment: no es clara tu explicación, por lo que he visto se puede instalar en cualquier proyecto StoryBook y te detecta el tipo de proyecto, lo que busco una vez creado el componente en ese framework como lo añado a un componente funcional propio, ahora nosotros lo estamos haciendo por separado y hay que hacer una especie de instalación como dependencia de cada componente creado en StoryBook, es una idea a lo mejor alguien tiene una mejor sugerencia.